# Autocorrect Hotkey

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

As a programmer I have experienced a very productive feature of many code editors where if you type something incorrectly, the code editor will detect this and allow you to rectify your mistake quickly using a hotkey combination to display a list of potential corrections from which you can choose the correction of choice. The interface presented when the shortcut combination is pressed is very similar to that of Microsoft Office's when you spell a word incorrectly and right click said word.

Is there a shortcut combination that I can press in Microsoft Office that will display the context menu with potential corrections? Currently I have to right click the misspelled word to view the menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most modern Windows keyboard have a Context Menu button (AKA the [Menu key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key)), which is equivilent to a right-click:

[image: Menu Key]

If you don't have that key, you can (also) use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Comment: Shift + F10 is perfect. Do you know how to change the shortcut combination? It's a little awkward.

Comment: @ByteBlast: You can use a simple AutoHotkey script to send Shift+F10 on a single key press, for example something like CapsLock or other key you might not be using often.